# How can i create a numeric pattern that starts from right to left side in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

i need to create a numeric pattern just like i mentioned in the title.
It should be like;

```
    0  0  0  0  1
    0  0  0  2  3
    0  0  4  5  6
    0  7  8  9 10
   11 12 13 14 15
```

I can do this;

```
    int[][] Example =    new int [5][5];      
    
    int c = 1;                              
    for (int satir = 0; satir < Example.length; satir++) { 
        for (int sutun = 0; sutun < Example.length; sutun++) { 
            if (sutun <= satir) {                        
                 if (c < 10) System.out.print(" ");   
                System.out.print(" " + c++);         
             } else {                               
                System.out.print("  " + 0);        
              }
         }
         System.out.println();                     
}

}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you start with a function that creates any single row

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;
    int k = 0;
    int[][] a = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j >= n - i - 1)
                a[i][j] = ++k;
            else
                a[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If your want auto margin

```
    int log = (int) Math.log10(n*(n+1)/2)+1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%"+log+"d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: is there any way to create this with arrays and aligned?

Comment: i just fixed it

Comment: it's not aligned when i run it. i'm using eclipse

Comment: @ArdaAltun Formatting can be fixed later. The logic is all that you asked for

Comment: use %2d to aligned it

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is simply count down the zeros in the row, then increment the counter for the remaining columns.

```
final int N = 5; // rows and columns
int zeros = N;
int counter = 0;
for (int row = 0 ; row < N; row++) {
    zeros--;  // first row 4 zeros, next 3, ...
    int z = 0; // pre-initialize the column counter
    // print the zeros
    for (; z < zeros; z++) { 
        System.out.printf("%02d ", 0);
    }
    // print the numbers
    for (; z < N; z++) {
        System.out.printf("%02d ", ++counter);
    }
    System.out.println(); // end line
}
```

You could extract out the inner loop to a function based on the number of zeros that are needed and the value of the first number that is required

```
int printLine(final int lineLength, int zeros, int n) {
    int column = 0;
    for (; column  < zeros; column++) {
        System.out.printf("%02d ", 0);
    }
    for (; column < lineLength; column++) {
        System.out.printf("%02d ", n++); 
    }
    System.out.println();
    return n; // to update the next line
}
```

Then you have

```
final int N = 5; // rows and columns
int lastValue = 1; // last value in row
for (int zeros = N - 1; zeros >= 0; zeros--) {
    lastValue = printLine(N, zeros, lastValue);
}
```

Which results in

```
00 00 00 00 01 
00 00 00 02 03 
00 00 04 05 06 
00 07 08 09 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
int n = 10;  // rows
int m = 10;  // columns
int[][] a = new int[n][m];
int counter = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(int j = m-1-i; j < m; j++) {
    a[i][j] = counter++;
  }
}

// print
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%02d ", a[i][j]));
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: OP never asked to store the numbers

Comment: i changed the code a bit;
int n = 5;  // rows
int m = 5;  // columns
int[][] a = new int[n][m];
int counter = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    a[i][m-1-j] = counter++;
  }
}

// print
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%2d ", a[i][j]));
  }
  System.out.println();
}
}}

but as you can see, the order of the numbers is kinda wrong, they "totally" go from right to left. can it be just like in the example i gave?

Comment: @ArdaAltun Updated the implementation - read too fast

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int size = 6;
for (int i = 0, k = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) 
        System.out.printf("%3d", i + j >= size - 1 ? k++ : 0);
    System.out.println();
}
```

result:

```
  0  0  0  0  0  1
  0  0  0  0  2  3
  0  0  0  4  5  6
  0  0  7  8  9 10
  0 11 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19 20 21
```